# Torque specs for Ford Focus inner tie rod

Tags: ford, suspension, focus, tie-rod

What is the correct torque for the inner tie rod on a 2002 Ford Focus SE wagon?

Comment: Also, if you could share your sources for your answer, I'd appreciate it. There is a bunch of conflicting info out there on forums and it's hard to trust a number if I don't know where it came from. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there is a spec for this ... You'd have to have some fancy tools to be able to measure the torque being applied, considering you cannot put a socket on it. Personally, I've only tightened this to tight, then bent the retaining tabs over to hold it in place. Never had an issue I'm aware of from this method. Maybe someone who does these more often can give a more qualified answer.

Comment: I am just using a torque wrench with the inner tie rod removal/install tool (which accepts 1/2 in. socket) to measure the torque.

Comment: I went ahead and did 70 ft lbs, because I had to get it done today, but I'd be interested if anyone finds the correct amount, for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ford's service information shows 80Nm or 60ft. lbs and some thread locker.

Comment: I was hoping you'd come along with a qualified answer. TY!